# Strict-Transport-Security influence on http reverse proxy that redirects to https

Tags: apache, hsts

The server response comes with HSTS header, and since I'm using reverse proxy HSTS header is also being sent through proxy response.
Since there are different domains (proxy and server) does HSTS make the browser automatically change the schema from http://proxyhost.com to https://proxyhost.com? or the preload list will call automatically https://serverhost.com when the user will request http://proxyhost.com?

Comment: HSTS affects to the domain where it is being loaded from, so if client only talks with the reverse proxy and it sees example.com it will affect only for example.com

Comment: so if the user only sees the reverse proxy domain, it will attache the HSTS header to the reverse proxy domain (reverse proxy forwarded this header from the main server), right? in this case I should unset HSTS header in the reverse proxy

Answer (score 2):

> does HSTS make the browser automatically change the schema from `http` to `https`

Indeed! and since:

> a reverse proxy HSTS header is also being sent through proxy response.

... the configuration of a reverse proxy can involuntarily make your domain set the`HSTS` header.

Took some while to see why my apache server sets the `HSTS` header - for I hadn't configured that in the apache web server. It was due to a `ReverseProxy`: as the foreign domain sets the`HSTS` header this header comes then (reverse proxy!) with my domain's name. This was then propagated to the client's browser which stores it. Thus, all my domain's sites (and in this case also all my subdomains!) where forced to use `https` (not when using e.g. `curl` of course, but `firefox`, `chromium` etc.).

Thanks for your question - it was already the perfect direction!

<s>In my case I simply could use a`RewriteRule` instead of a `reverse proxy` :) but this of course depends on your scenario.</s>

You also gave the proper answer in your comment:

> in this case I should unset HSTS header in the reverse proxy

Right! Just add `Header unset Strict-Transport-Security` directly after the `ProxyPassReverse` directive, and you can use a reverse proxy without inherit the `HSTS` header.